# how to prevent redirect to index.html after log in or sign up?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I recently implemented a new homepage (index.html) on my rails app (into folder public/index.html) with /signin and /signup paths. Before I implemented index.html on my website, I have been redirecting users to root_url (which is home.html.erb) after sign in or sign up. 
When they sign out, I've been redirecting them to root_path.

The problem is that after this new index.html, when users try to log in or sign up, they get redirected back to index.html. Is there a place to have them log in successfully to the original root_url without requiring many code edits?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

UsersController

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This is what I have in my routes.rb

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

Comment: Find the login/sign_up action in either your session_controller or users_controller and you will se a redirect action at the end of both. Instead of redirect_to `whatever`, change it to redirect_to root_path

Comment: I changed to root_path under def create in both controllers but I'm still getting the same issue. I posted up the codes in the updated post

Comment: can you run rake routes and see if the home.html.erb is really the root_path

Comment: I ran rake routes and this is what I found: root /    static_pages#home

Comment: please read the two upvoted answers

Answer (score 1):

First off the only difference between `root_url` and `root_path` (and in general between `foo_url` and `foo_path`) is that the former is a full url (i.e. http://example.com/...) whereas the latter is just the path (the bit after the hostname). For a simple redirect they'll have the same result.

If `public/index.html` exists then that is where visits to '/', (i.e. root_path) will go.

If you want users to be sent to a different page after signup then change your redirect. For example if your routes file had

```
get '/home' => 'home#index', :as => :home
```

then redirecting to `home_path` would send people to the index action of the home controller.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your `public/index.html` overrides your `root_path` Rails route.

You cannot access the `root_path` if there is a file called `index.html` in your public directory.

You need to rename `index.html` to something else or use another path other than your `root_path`

**EDIT:**

Another option is to have two different erb templates for the root_path. Then in the controller action for the root_path, you could do this:

```
class StaticPages < ApplicationController
  def home
    if user_signed_in?
      render 'home_signed_in'
    else
      render 'home_signed_out'
    end
  end
end
```

You would then need to create two erb templates at,

`/app/views/static_pages/home_signed_in.html.erb`

and

`/app/views/static_pages/home_signed_out.html.erb`

You would also need to define or replace the `user_signed_in?` method in my example code with your own method to detect if the user is signed in. And don't forget to remove `/public/index.html`

Comment: If I rename index.html to something else, how can I make this page come up when someone goes to www.mydomain.com?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. You can only have `index.html` or `root_path`. The two conflict and your web server will choose the static `index.html` over the Rails `root_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `root_path` with `home_ControllerName_path`, where ControllerName must be the name of the controller handling the home action.

Comment: he is doing it already. The name of the controller is `static_pages`

Comment: @johbones Based on your code, it must be `home_static_page_path`

Comment: I tried 'redirect_to home_static_page_path' in my controllers, but I get this error: undefined local variable or method `home_static_page_path' for #<SessionsController:0x4e83070>

Comment: Try with this `redirect_to :controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'home'`

Comment: unfortunately I think this may not work. This is the error that I got: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in SessionsController (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action.")

Comment: As mentioned in the error you got, you may check your code and be sure that you called `redirect_to` ONE time.

Answer (score 0):

go to your routes.rb file and make following change

```
root :to => 'main#home_page'
```

you can redirect to any route by modifying root:  in config/routes.rb file